# Access denied issue in docker container node application

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a MERN stack application. I deployed the app on render cloud. I noticed that my image upload functionality is not working but works on local machine. I 'dockerized' the node application.
The error message I got when I tried to upload image is this:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'images/1666890887146download.png'
```

First, I am using `multer` npm package to handle image upload. The image is saved inside a folder called `image` in my `api` project folder. I think because of the user access in dockerfile, that is why the access is denied.
Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM  node:lts-alpine

 WORKDIR /app

 COPY package*.json ./

  COPY client/package*.json client/
  RUN npm run install-client --only=production


  COPY api/package*.json api/
  RUN npm run install-api --only=production



   COPY client/ client/
   RUN npm run client-build --prefix client


 COPY api/ api/



 USER node

 CMD [ "npm", "start", "--prefix", "api" ]



 EXPOSE 5000
```

Here is my `multer` image upload function:

```
 const ALLOWED_FORMATS = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg'];

    //login to upload images using libery called multer
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({//choosing destination of the file
    destination:(req, file, cb) =>{
    if(ALLOWED_FORMATS.includes(file.mimetype)){
         cb(null, "./images")
    }else{
        cb(new Error('Not supported file type!'), false)
    }
   
}, filename:(req, file,cb)=> {//choosing file name
   cb(null, req.body.name) 
  }
 });

 const upload = multer({storage:storage})
```

I am sensing that the `node` User I assigned in `dockerfile` does not have access to read and write file in the `image` folder. My logics rely on that because after uploading the image from the `image` folder to cloudinary, I also deleted it immediately.
Is there a way I can assign `node` User the permission to read and write files in image folder? I am not too familiar with docker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the node user to the sudo group...

`sudo usermod -aG sudo $USER`

or you can give permissions to the user using something like

`chown -R $USER:$USER images/`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, where will this line of code appear

Comment: Add this right after `USER node` command in Dockerfile